# Call function outside parent object in a class

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript

```
class Test
    f1: -> console.log 'f1'
    f2: -> console.log 'f2'

    f:
        f3: -> f1()

test = new Test
test.f.f3()
```

When I run this in NodeJS, I get this:

```
ReferenceError: f1 is not defined
```

---

I want to run `f1` from `f.f3`. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: There's really no relationship between the object "f" and the parent object of "f", so you'd have to explicitly pass a reference to the parent object into "f3". (*edit* oops maybe I'm wrong :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer was not correct, but this works (a slight modification):

```
class Test
  f1: -> console.log 'f1'
  f2: -> console.log 'f2'
  f: =>
    f3: => @f1()

test = new Test
test.f().f3()
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but then I have to call `f` too. Wouldn't this lead to some side effects later? And something I need be careful about when using this?

Comment: The trouble is that the `this` pointer when `f` is defined as an object becomes a pointer to the class itself, so the method it tries to call becomes `Test.f1()`. Since `f1` is not a static method that does not work. My workaround should not introduce any significant side effects and effectively carries the correct instance pointer (`this`) through to the inner function. If you are able to make f1 and f2 static functions, something similar to your original attempt except using `@f1()` should work.

Comment: I tried making `f1` static (`@f1`). It works properly. But I want to ask which method is better? Is it good practice to make `f1` static?

Comment: If it never accesses any instance data, yes, declaring it static is the way to go. But if you need access to any instance data (data which is unique to each instance after you `new` it), then you have no other choice than to declare it as a member function (non-static).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll go with your method, because in some places I'm using instance data. Thanks! :D